# Intersection and Collada-Three.JS

Tags: three.js, intersection, loader, collada

I used the following code to implement intersection. It works fine for defined geometries in the code. But it does not detect intersections with Collada objects.

```
        document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', Identify, false );
        function Identify( event ) {

                event.preventDefault();
                mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
                mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

                raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );
                if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
                    if ( INTERSECTED != intersects[ 0 ].object ) {
                        if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );
                        INTERSECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
                        INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.color.getHex();
                        INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( 0xff0000 );
                    }
                } else {
                    if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );
                    INTERSECTED = null;
                }

        }
```

How can I include Collada geometries into the intersection matrix?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem (in my case i was importing a 6 axis robot then each link was a child object of the previous link) so intersectObjects must be executed recursively in the scene by putting the second parameter to true, as stated in the docs:
http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Raycaster

you can try changing you code to:

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by adding the following code after Colladaloader to push all objects.

```
var ToIntersect = [];   
dae.traverse(function(child) {
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
        ToIntersect.push(child);
    }
});


...

var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( ToIntersect );
```